# How to find my Graphics card's Memory

Tags: graphics

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

shows ...

```
*-display              
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:63 memory:c3000000-c3ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:7000(size=64)

 *-display
   description: 3D controller
   product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:65 memory:c4000000-c4ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
```

Then I tried

```
amruth@HP-Ci5:~$ lspci | grep VGA
```

which returns

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

Then I tried

```
amruth@HP-Ci5:~$ lspci -v -s 00:02.0
```

which returns

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2337
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 64
    Memory at c3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 7000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

From this can I conclude that my graphics card is just 256Mb. This is my new HP laptop[HP 15-r240TX Notebook (5th Gen Ci5/ 8GB/ 1TB/ Free DOS/ 2GB Graph) (L8P42PA)] from Flipcart. So I plan to request replacement. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Is there any chance that my Graphics card is not detected? I used 'hardinfo' and 'sysinfo' tools. Both did not show the presence of Graphics card

Answer (score 3):

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

mark the digits in front of it. Then do...

```
lspci -v -s {digits}
```

Example from my machine:

```
~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
[AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
```

and

```
$ lspci -vm -s 01:00.0
Device: 01:00.0
Class:  VGA compatible controller
Vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Device: Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
SVendor:    Acer Incorporated [ALI]
SDevice:    Radeon HD 6650M
```

will show all the details of the videocard. edit: seems not all show the memory of the card. This methods works for more than just your videocard: details on network card both wired and wireless, USB controller are also shown (just change the command to 02:00.0, 03:00.0. My audio is on 01:00.1; just check the 1st command for the digits).

---

So another method:

```
lspci -v | grep VGA -A12
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Radeon HD 6650M
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c0300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at c0340000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

- 256Mb

Comment: this is the right answer...

Answer (score 0):

Download SystemInfo from the official repos, or via terminal:

`sudo apt-get install sysinfo`

Then, open straight from terminal:

`sysinfo`

Now you can see all you need to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following command:

```
lspci -vvnn  | grep -Pzo "(?s)\[03.*?\sprefetchable\) \K\[size=(\d+)M\]"
```

Prefer to grep for `\[03` as video cards are not always listed with `[0300] VGA compatible controller`. They could be a `[0380] Display controller`, or a `[0302] 3D controller`.

The result for my system:

```
[0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21fb]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 32
    Region 0: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Region 2: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
```

is:

```
[size=256M]
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this post with a similar question, about how much shared memory is actually in use, and how much is claimable, by the integrated graphics in my laptop. I found all three of these commands helpful, although the amount of memory returned differed among them (could be measuring min vs. current vs. max allocated shared RAM -- not sure). The commands are:

- `sudo lshw -c display`
- `lspci | grep VGA` -->  --> `lspci -v -s <PCI_ID>`
- `glxinfo -B`

**LSHW**

In my case, `sudo lshw -c display` returns:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=3200x1800 visual=truecolor xres=3200 yres=1800
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:150 memory:6022000000-6022ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**LSPCI**

The `lspci` tool gives me memory addresses, which presumably could be translated into size, but that's beyond my capability. The output from `lspci | grep VGA` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
```

Plugging the PCI ID at the front of the string back into lspci and asking for more detail, we have `lspci -v -s 00:02.0` which returns:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 150
    Memory at 6022000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    [virtual] Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

**OpenGL / GLXInfo**

Finally, `glxinfo -B` returns 3072MB. I'm guessing that's the maximum amount the integrated graphics is allowed to claim from the shared (system) RAM. Here's the full output:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2)  (0x3ea0)
    Version: 19.2.8
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

So, depending on what you're looking for, any or all of these commands may be useful.