# how i can know my graphics card memory size?

Tags: ati, ram

I want to know my video memory size and i tried method with

```
lshw -c display
```

But it shows

```
 *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
   resources: irq:29 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d1000000-d101ffff ioport:a000(size=256) memory:d0000000-d001ffff
```

I tried method with sysinfo but program doesn't show my graphics card, with hardinfo same problem

My graphics card AMD Radeon HD 5450

Comment: i tried those methods but it doesn't work

Comment: Try running "sudo lshw" in terminal

Comment: define "it doesn`t work", what did you encounter?

Comment: Aizuddin Zali - hardinfo and sysinfo doesn't show my graphics card. And "sudo lshw -businfo | grep -i display" doesn't show memory size.

Comment: the output you posted in the question are for HDMI sound card. Can you edit your question and put `lshw -c display` output?

Comment: Aizuddin Zali - Done

Comment: @righN your Ubuntu version?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: please refer [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-linux-vga-video-card-ram/)

Comment: i tried that method with lspci from website that Ravan give me and it shows me i have only 256mb when catalyst control center show 512mb

Comment: @righN this one should work for you http://askubuntu.com/questions/617401/how-to-find-my-graphics-cards-memory

Answer (score 1):

**Install i-nex**:

I-nex can tell you in-depth statistics of your system hardware, taking in everything from your CPU to your sound card along the way.

- The first repository is for **Gambas**. Gambas is the name of an object-oriented dialect of the BASIC programming language and is required to run i-nex.

  To add the Gambas repository add:

  ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gambas-team/gambas3
  ```
- The next repository is for the i-nex application:

  ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kranich/cubuntu
  ```

Now update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install i-nex
```

Comment: not complete, after installation and then how?

Comment: Why'd you need two repositories for one application? I-nex seems to be available from the latter repo (https://launchpad.net/~i-nex-development-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

Comment: Have you installed it?

Comment: @wildcard they are not the same application.. the first repository is for additional software required to run i-nex

Comment: i got this error "E: Unable to locate package i-nex" i run all commands like you write

Comment: @William Ok, that still seems strange though. Also, the latter is not available: `http://ppa.launchpad.net/i-nex-development-team/stable/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`

Comment: @wildcard i don't understand why that would be strange. Anyway source is http://i-nex.linux.pl/install/

Comment: @William sorry ,that PPA is not for 15.04 ...OP using 15.04

Comment: @William I changed ppa for 15.04.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard please let me know the new ppa got any errors?

Comment: @William please explain and elaborate the answer...Downvoter please undown vote =)

Comment: @William Yes, that repository is working great. I didn't need to add the gambas repo - it fetched those libraries from archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ . I got an error while installing it(Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) ) but I-nex runs fine

Comment: Answer has been edited with more information. @Wildcard glad it's working for you.

Comment: @righN please try answer by william..let me know working or not?

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 i-nex
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
I got this error when installing

Comment: but i-nex working but why it's showing me i only have 256m memory when on windows shows me 512mb and in ubuntu catalyst control center shows 512mb